# How to deselect the checked checkbox from EnhancedGrid's indirectSelection plugin

Tags: dojo

I used EnhancedGrid's indirectSelection plugin to implement a table. There is a column of checkbox in the table.

The user can check the checkbox and do something by clicking on a button on the page.

But when the user returns to the main page with the EnhancedGrid's indirectSelection plugin, the checkbox is still checked.

Could you please let me know how to refresh the UI with EnhancedGrid's indirectSelection plugin and ensure no checkbox is checked when the user clicks on the link to go back to the main page?

```
         var mygrid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: "id",
        store: store,
        autowidth:"true", 
        rowselector:"15px",
        plugins: {indirectSelection: {headerSelector:true, width:"80px", styles:"text-align: center;"}},            
        keepRows: "30",
        rowsPerPage: "10",
        style:"height:300px",
        structure: layout},"mygridContainer");  
    mygrid.startup();
    dojo.connect(mygrid, "onApplyEdit", function(row){
        store.save();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dojo.connect(mygrid, "onApplyEdit", function(row){
    store.save();
    mygrid.update();
});
```